# Write to beginning of the buffer in Golang?

Tags: go

I have:

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer
s := "something to do"
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
   buffer.WriteString(s)
}
```

Which appends to the buffer, is it possible to write to the beginning of a buffer?

Comment: Do you want to _insert_ to the beginning, or _overwrite_ content at the beginning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the underlying `buf` not exported from `bytes.Buffer`, you may use:

```
buffer.WriteString("B")
s := buffer.String()
buffer.Reset()
buffer.WriteString("A")
buffer.WriteString(s)
```

Try this [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bUxFjbn3ek):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString("B")
    s := buffer.String()
    buffer.Reset()
    buffer.WriteString("A" + s)
    fmt.Println(buffer.String())
}
```

output:

```
AB
```

Answer (score 6):

*Inserting* to the beginning is not possible, see Amd's answer for a "workaround". For *overwriting* content at the beginning, read on.

Note that the internal byte slice `Buffer.buf` is not exported, but the method [`Buffer.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes) returns a slice sharing the same backing array as the `Buffer.buf` internal slice.

This means if you create a new [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) by calling [`Bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer), and pass this slice after *reslicing* it to zero length and capacity retained, you can write to the beginning of the buffer, *overwriting* original data of the first buffer.

See this example:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf.WriteString("Hello  World")
fmt.Println("buf:", buf)

buf2 := bytes.NewBuffer(buf.Bytes()[:0])
buf2.WriteString("Gopher")
fmt.Println("buf:", buf)
fmt.Println("buf2:", buf2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SzZQZmQnxJ)):

```
buf: Hello  World
buf: Gopher World
buf2: Gopher
```

Note: Using this technique, you can also overwrite content at arbitrary position, by reslicing using the desired index instead of `0` and passing the slice. For example:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf.WriteString("Hello  World")
fmt.Println("buf:", buf)

buf2 := bytes.NewBuffer(buf.Bytes()[6:6]) // Start after the "Hello"
buf2.WriteString("Gopher")
fmt.Println("buf:", buf)
fmt.Println("buf2:", buf2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-TIKSO__yO)):

```
buf: Hello  World
buf: Hello Gopher
buf2: Gopher
```

Note that the "manipulation" of the content through the slice returned by `Buffer.Bytes()` may only succeed until the `Buffer` is modified, after that there's a chance that `Buffer` allocates a new backing array and the one you have will be "detached" (and so further modification on it will not be reflected in the original `Buffer`):

> The slice is valid for use only until the next buffer modification (that is, only until the next call to a method like Read, Write, Reset, or Truncate).

Comment: +1 very detailed answer. I wonder if the slice is valid `... only until the next call to a method like Read, Write, Reset, or Truncate` or before buffer grow?

Comment: @ozy The internal slice of the `Buffer` will not grow by itself, only if you call certain methods on `Buffer`. But until you do, you're free to modify its content via the slice you acquired by calling `Byffer.Bytes()`.