# How to append to the beginning of a file in Go?

Tags: file, go

I want to append to the beginning of a file. Don't get me wrong, I can append it but I want the last written string to be top (first line) of the file.

Comment: This is not how files work. You can append to the end of the file or you can overwrite existing contents, but you can't insert.

Comment: You have to write a new file, first write the new data, then write the old contents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write to beginning of the buffer in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231761/write-to-beginning-of-the-buffer-in-golang)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a LIFO?

Answer (score 1):

This example program "appends" to the start of the file

It makes assumptions that the file contents are lines with line endings and that
nothing else is modifying the file

(and probably some other assumptions too..this is a simple example)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    addline := "aaa first\n"
    // make a temporary outfile
    outfile, err := os.Create("newfoo.txt")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer outfile.Close()

    // open the file to be appended to for read
    f, err := os.Open("foo.txt")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    // append at the start
    _, err = outfile.WriteString(addline)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    // read the file to be appended to and output all of it
    for scanner.Scan() {

        _, err = outfile.WriteString(scanner.Text())
        _, err = outfile.WriteString("\n")
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // ensure all lines are written
    outfile.Sync()
    // over write the old file with the new one
    err = os.Rename("newfoo.txt", "foo.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```